# MSbuild - What's best practise for adding in 3rd party reference libraries on a build server?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration, jenkins

I'm learning builds using MSBuild and running them on my newly installed Jenkins CI server.

The problem I'm having is with external dependencies, such as Automapper.dll, and them not being on the build server, so my build fails with 'Could not locate the assembly "AutoMapper"', which is understandable.

I'm not sure how to approach this at all. I've searched for the last two days on SO and Google, but just end up more confused. Should I somehow be adding these files into my VS solution, or should them be in the SVN somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most basic and common approach is to have a `lib\` folder within your source control, and reference those from your solution, using relative paths. That way the build server can locate the files just as your development machines do.

One great approach is to use [NuGet](http://nuget.org/) for package dependencies. [Team City](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) by JetBrains already supports it out-of-the-box.

[Here's more info](http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/dependency-management-in-net-with-nuget-and-teamcity/) on NuGet in general, and it also shows how it works within Team City:

Comment: I'm using SVN with trunk, branch and tag folders. Would I create a single lib folder that all of the versions of the project in their respective folders would share?

Comment: You should keep it closer to the code, since it's possible you might need to upgrade an external reference in one branch but not the others.
I keep the libs folder at the same level as the solution file, and consider it to be part of the code I branch.

Comment: Yack! Keeping binaries in source control is a HUGE waste of space: the diff between previous binary file and the new binary file IS the new binary file.

Comment: I agree. That's why I also mentioned how to use Nuget for this.

Answer (score 1):

The CI machine needs to be able to build the project from scratch. This includes third-party references. In my experience, it's easiest to create a "ThirdParty" folder somewhere in your source control structure, and reference the assemblies out of that folder.

Comment: @DMB Where would I reference the third party folder? In my proj file? Also, is it possible to reference it as "svn://myRepo/libraries" etc?

Comment: I have no experience with SVN, so I can't help you there. I would generally put the folder containing my third-party assemblies somewhere within the normal branching structure of the application, so you can track changes to the third party assemblies you're using.

Answer (score 0):

We use NuGet, which places everything under a 'packages' folder. As long as they are **all** in one place, I think you will be OK.